# looping over multiple async_generator objects together

Tags: python, asynchronous

I started working out some problems to master python asyncio module. What I wanted to create is a 'clock' which basically just prints out the time after program started in Hour:Minute:Second format. I thought of making three async_generators and looping over those three async_generators using a for loop in a seperate async method. Using builtin zip() method for this gives me the following error.

```
TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration
```

code :

```
import asyncio

second = 1

async def seconds():
    while True:
        for i in range(1,61):
            await asyncio.sleep(second)
            yield i

async def minutes():
    while True:
        for i in range(1,61):
            await asyncio.sleep(60*second)
            yield i

async def hours():
    while True:
        for i in range(1,61):
            await asyncio.sleep(60*60*second)
            yield i

async def clock():
    for s,m,h in zip(seconds(),minutes(),hours()):
        print('{0}:H{1}:M{2}:S'.format(h,m,s))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(clock())
```

My question is, doesn't async_genertator objects support iteration? When I checked, i could see that async_generator object hours() has ____aiter____ method. Isn't ____aiter____ iterable? What is wrong with the code I wrote.